# How to use any control event for WPF command

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am wondering how I can use any event of any control to invoke a custom COMMAND. All examples shows Keyboard Keys are input gesture, and Button and MenuItem clicks.

What if I want to invoke a command on LostFocus.

Comment: You can put an event handler in code behind, and call the command from there (but how to do it without breaking MVVM is another story...)

Comment: You can use an `EventTrigger` from Blend Behaviors (`System.Windows.Interactivity`) and pair it with an `InvokeCommandAction`.